# Magento 2 Check if a Variable contains JSON encoded code or not?

Tags: magento2, json

I have a variable `$image`, Sometimes it containes JSON Encoded value and sometimes it is not.
**What I need?**
If `$image` doesn't have JSON encoded data, I want to do my custom code.

I am trying this:

```
public function isJSON($string){
    return is_string($string) && is_array($this->jsonHelper->jsonDecode($string, true)) && (json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE) ? true : false;
}

if(!isJSON($image)){
   $decode_image = $image;
}
```

But it is not working, Please help me.

Comment: I thing is JSON function like this - is_JSON($image)

Comment: @AnasMansuri Is is_JSON work on Magento2??

Comment: yes. try with is_JSON() it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `is_JSON($image)` issue solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isValid()` method of this class `\Magento\Framework\Serialize\JsonValidator`. It's simple to use and returns bool value.